# how can I populate a N at the beginning of 5 numbers and/or 3 number followed by two letters example N123UA N12345

Tags: excel

how can I populate a N at the beginning of 5 numbers and/or 3 number followed by two letters 
           example excel
                         N123UA
                         N12345

Answer (score 0):

For in cell formatting I believe you can not combine both number and text format at the same place, either you can set the format for numbers or for alphanumeric text.

You can either set it to be "N"00000 or "N"000 for numbers

or as "N"@ or "N"@"UA" or whatever you require for text

Comment: use your formula it auto populates random info.

Comment: isn't it what you have asked? it is populating a random number of three digits starting with N and ending at two alphabets

Comment: yes I'm sorry I should have clarified. When I type into a cell say12345 I can populate a N in front of 12345 with format cells under the numbers tab then custom with this   "N"0000 but if I also need the N to populate if I type in for (example) 123SW OR 456UA. Does that help?

Comment: If it solves your problem you can mark this post as the selected answer and upvote it.